# How to solve a dependency between Base and Derived class data

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

So I have this class kind of class:

```
class Base
{
public:
Base() { task_ = std::thread(&DexHandlerBase::running_task, this); }
virtual ~Base(){ /*send signal to task_ to stop then */ task_.join();}

protected:
virtual int some_check(int) = 0;

private:
void running_task() { some_check(123); }
std::thread task_;

}

class Derived
{
protected:
int some_check(int) override; //here I use my_data

private:
std::string my_data = "test";
}
```

An exception spawn up sometimes when the program close.

My guess is that the default Destructor of derived is called, Derived default destructor run and then `my_data` get destructed. Then the Base class destructor is called and it signal the thread that its going to be destroyed and wait. But the thread is running a task that is a call to a virtual function , this function use my_data that no longer exist.

So there is a dependency from the Base class to the Derived class data. I dont want to move data up, and the function has to be virtual. Shall I override the destructor in each derived class so it closes the thread or is there a better design for this ?

Comment: it seems to me that your `Base` has to be more abstract, and delegate finishing the task to some (possibly pure) virtual function, which is overriden as needed in the derived classes

Comment: just to make it clear, this doesn't really relate to `thread` or `virtual`, you could simply pass `Derived&` to base and use it in destructor (or just cast).

Comment: Yes, apple apple, if i just had a reference to Derived class in Base destructor that was trying to work on my_data the same issue arise. But here im really questioning with this async design in mind.

Comment: When a destructor calls a virtual function (directly or indirectly) it calls the vision defined in the class that the destructor belongs to. Yes, `my_data` no longer exists; but the destructor doesn't call `Derived::some_check`. That's not the problem. (If you're coming from a Java background, Java has a major mis-feature that it **does** call the derived class version)

Comment: @PeteBecker that is correct, although the invocation is at constructor in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problems when trying to run async operations in Base classes. Most likely after the destructor of `Derived` is called, the `task_` tries to call `virtual int some_check(int) = 0;` which is pure virtual, so it is illegal, because `Derived` doesn't exist anymore. You should make sure that your `Derived::~Derived()` stops the asyc operation by `/*send signal to task_ to stop then */`. E.g. implement `protected` `Base::stopTask()` and call it in `Derived` DTor.

Comment: But this stopTask will be about the same for all Derived class, so its copy/pasting same code again and again.

Comment: This answer is on the right track: the problem is almost certainly that call to a pure virtual function. The simplest solution is to **implement** that function. You're allowed to implement a pure virtual function; you can't do it inline in the class definition, so you have to either put it after the class definition in the header and mark it `inline` or define it as an ordinary function in a .cpp file.

Comment: Ok i get what you say. But i think also that sometimes the Derived class get destroyed while the thread call to Derived::some_check is still running. Derived is stored in another class unique_ptr, when that class is destroyed it call Derived destructor while the thread of Baseclass might be in the process of running the virtual function. If i just implement the pure virtual call i prevent the func to be run again but what if im in the middle of the call when it gets destroyed ?

Comment: No no, `stopTask` should be implemented in the base class and called in the `Derived` class destructor. This way you will prevent calls to `some_check` after `Derived` destruction. Or follow Pete Becker advice, however I never tried it.

Comment: Yes agreed. Do you see any better solution, because its not optimal as it imposes some restriction on the Derived class , it needs to not forgot do that in its destructor.

Comment: Yep, that's true. Currently I don't have any better idea :(

Comment: Ultimately i did that with a macro def as destructor is same for all derived and I wanted to simplify destructor + all constructors / assignment operators definition. Still i dont think this design is great but it works.